# Remove icon from launcher

Tags: java, android, icons, launcher

It is most popular problem and no one know how to resolve it...

For example:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/add"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
```

And now i need to hide android:icon or just i wanna to remove it

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
```

But in this case i have default android icon -_-
It is possible to permanent remove this icon?

Comment: did you try with getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false); ?

Comment: getSupportActionBar() is undefined and getActionBar() is only for api 11+ but i need any resolve for api 8. Do you know why getSupportActionBar() method is undefined and i cannot import it?

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: No, i am not using this lib. It is good library for create any action bars, buttons and something like that?

Comment: yes it is the a library for older mobile in order to get the action bar. Is your question related to actionbar?

Comment: It is related to top menu on android screen so i thing yes. I try to create menu with dynamic elements and one static element for open new fragmen or activity where user can choose any icons to add. When user put any icon from this fragmen/activity this icon will be add to top menu like a new item. It is good solution? or meaby is any easly solution for do it?

Answer (score 0):

This can remove your launcher icon after next reboot:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Also this link can help you too:

[Hide application launcher icon in title bar when activity starts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430712/hide-application-launcher-icon-in-title-bar-when-activity-starts-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You may create you own icon picture.

So you may try just create picture which has necessary size and consist from transparent background only.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution! I had began learn java and android a couple of day ago, so my solution need verify by someone more experienced then me. Here u have the solution:

**Step1**

In AndroidManifest.xml file application section we need to declare NoTitleBar theme.

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
...
</application>
```

**Step2**

Now we have no title bar when our application loader (We set Theme.NoTitleBar), so we need to create it or change android:theme. I take a second option, so:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            ....
    }
    ....
}
```

R.style.AppTheme is a style created by us but we can use anyone available style from android  API.

**Step3**
Now our title bar is back but still we have our icon and title. So we need turn off it and now we have two options for do this. First is when we use android api 11 or later and we not need use ActionBarSherlock libs and second is for application lower then api 11.

**API 11 or lower**

```
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            ...
}
...
```

**API 11 or later**

```
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            ...
}
...
```

So, in first case we use default getActionBar() to manage actionBar but in second case we use getSupportActionBar from ActionBarSherlock

Done :)