# hiding application logo and title displayed for a fraction of seconds before starting of activity if custom action bar layout is used

Tags: android, android-actionbar

With reference to question raised at SO link :

[Hide application launcher icon in title bar when activity starts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430712/hide-application-launcher-icon-in-title-bar-when-activity-starts-in-android)

What should I do if I don't want to use even a logo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I do if I don't want to use even a logo ?

You can use [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) instead of old ActionBar. [Here's](http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example) a great and quick tutorial for Toolbar implementation.

Comment: Thank you @MatusMak for helpful information.
I found another link which was helpful to develop Android toolbar with menu options available on it :
http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html